# extjs store-combobox not being sorted as expected

Tags: sorting, extjs

In my extjs project when I have this store loaded... which populates a combobox, the combobox is not displaying the results in sort order.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication4.model.ClientListModel', {
extend: 'ExtApplication4.model.Base',

requires: ['ExtApplication4.model.Base'],

fields: [
    { name: 'clientName' },
    { name: 'ClientShortCode' }
],

sorters: [
    {
        property: 'clientName',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }
],

sortRoot: 'clientName',
sortOnLoad: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining sorters on your `model`. You should define sorters on your `store`.

Be careful of the `remoteSort` property. It defines if the store is sorted locally (on client) or remotely (on server).

Also, you shouldn't need to require extended classes.

Comment: thanks... you are correct.  I sorted on store and it worked!  the extended class was me following a tutorial... not even sure what that really is.

Comment: Inheritance is one of the base concepts of OOP - Object Oriented Programming. If you are not familiar with OOP, you should really read into it.